# Is there a way to let the extension open a windows native app in compatibility mode or as Administrator

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, manifest

I am new on chrome extension developing so maybe this is a naive question.
The Chrome extension native messaging feature (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) can start a host and run the host binary.

For Windows, the manifest.json file is like:

{
  "name": "com.my_company.my_application", 
  "description": "My Application",
  "path": "C:\Program Files\My Application\chrome_native_messaging_host.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}

So here is my question, is there a way to use Chrome extension start a windows local app with compatibility mode? Or open as Administrator?

Comment: No, Chrome doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: OK. Thanks though.